# Kivy - combining KV with python logic

Tags: python, kivy

I'm struggling since yesterday with my kivy application and I'm in the dead end.

I'm a newbie programmer and I decided that I want to create app in Kivy, with logic in Python. App will collect status of the devices connected to the network through REST API.

Rest api works well, and I have all the infos that I needed. Also, my graphical side of the project is done. Now I want to connect those two things into one. Here's the problem.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
from kivy.config import Config
from os import listdir
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from rest import sniffer


# Window config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '500')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
Config.write()

# Variables

mir_list = []
mir_dict = {'MiR_S161': '10.173.175.117',
        'MiR_S162': '10.173.175.121',
        'MiR_S319': '10.173.175.120',
        'MiR_S325': '10.173.175.119',
        'MiR_S326': '10.173.175.116',
        'MiR_S327': '10.173.175.118'
        }

# Kivy

kv_path = './kv/'
for kv in listdir(kv_path):
    Builder.load_file(kv_path+kv)


# Declare screens

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MiRScreen161(Screen):
pass

class MiRScreen162(Screen):
    pass

class MiRScreen319(Screen):
    pass

class MiRScreen325(Screen):
    pass

class MiRScreen326(Screen):
    pass

class MiRScreen327(Screen):
    pass

# Create the screen manager

sm = ScreenManager(transition = SlideTransition())
sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main'))
sm.add_widget(MiRScreen161(name='MiR_S161'))
sm.add_widget(MiRScreen162(name='MiR_S162'))
sm.add_widget(MiRScreen319(name='MiR_S319'))
sm.add_widget(MiRScreen325(name='MiR_S325'))
sm.add_widget(MiRScreen326(name='MiR_S326'))
sm.add_widget(MiRScreen327(name='MiR_S327'))

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'MiR Sniffer'
        return sm



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

That's my main code - it refers to the other .py script with the REST handling which I wrote before.

```
<MainScreen>:
oft = oftbutton
GridLayout:
    cols: 2
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            size: (400,200)
            source: 'mir-200.png'
            pos_hint: {'left':1, 'top':0.98}
            size_hint: None, None
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        Label:
            halign: 'left'
            font_size: 70
            size_hint: (None,None)
            size: (140, 10)
            text: 'MiR Sniffer'
            pos: (105,70)
        Label:
            halign: 'left'
            font_size: 15
            size_hint: (None,None)
            size: (140, 10)
            text: 'Igor Czyrski \ngithub.com/czyrski'
            pos: (0,20)

    StackLayout:
        orientation: 'bt-rl'
        Button:
            id: oftbutton
            text: 'MiR_S161'
            size: 200, 75
            size_hint: None, None
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'MiR_S161'
        Button:
            text: 'MiR_S162'
            size: 200, 75
            size_hint: None, None
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'MiR_S162'
        Button:
            text: 'MiR_S319'
            size: 200, 75
            size_hint: None, None
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'MiR_S319'
        Button:
            text: 'MiR_S325'
            size: 200, 75
            size_hint: None, None
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'MiR_S325'
        Button:
            text: 'MiR_S326'
            size: 200, 75
            size_hint: None, None
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'MiR_S326'
        Button:
            text: 'MiR_S327'
            size: 200, 75
            size_hint: None, None
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'MiR_S327'
```

And that's kv file.

Now I need to in every 3 minutes get a callback of REST api functions and present  output in the places of Buttons text.

I'm stuck - as I said I'm not a skillfull programmer. Can someone take a look and try to get me on the right track?

Comment: You can set the text of a particular Button in your UI by referencing it by `id` and setting it's `text` attribute. As far as using time intervals, I would read into the `Clock` object here: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html

Comment: So, if I will set ID of every button I can change it's text content by just assigning some variable into it? I mean:
   new_text = button_id.text
Right?

Comment: You will do something along the lines of `self.ids.oftbutton.text = new_text` in your Python logic (where `self` refers to the screen instance that your button is a child of)

Comment: Ahh, It's so confusing for the newbies, and documentation isn't so easy to understand. Still don't how to use it. How can I use Clock to call function? Where should I put it? As example I want to call function sniffer.get_actual_status in every 3 minutes.

Comment: It states pretty clearly in the docs: `Clock.schedule_interval(my_callback, 180)` would equate to 3 mins and `my_callback` would just be your function that you are calling.